# How to perform regex AND operation?

Tags: regex, scala

I have string "bob wants to go to alice place". I want to match pattern something like that (alice & bob).So I have tried

```
(.*alice.*.*bob.*)
```

but this doesn't work as order matters here.
How can I do this using regex.

Comment: Your pattern [does actually match "alice & bob"](https://regex101.com/r/WveQZP/1). What's the problem?

Comment: I want to match this pattern with "bob wants to go to alice place" string

Comment: using lookahead assertion `(?=.*alice)(?=.*bob).*`

Comment: [One lookahead would probably suffice](https://regex101.com/r/KRtwaO/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match two (or more) patterns in any order, you can use lookahead assertion, because it allows to match a pattern without moving input cursor.

```
^(?=.*alice)(?=.*bob).*
```

the start of input anchor is to avoid unnecessary backtracking.

Comment: if you want to ensure that alice and bob match only if they appear as words, wrap them with `\b`, for example: `^(?=.*\balice\b)(?=.*\bbob\b).*`